# Extended Errors do not have message or stack trace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When running this snippet through BabelJS:

```
class FooError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

let error = new FooError('foo');
console.log(error, error.message, error.stack);
```

it outputs

```
{}
```

which is not what I expect. Running

```
error = new Error('foo');
console.log(error, error.message, error.stack);
```

produces

```
{} foo Error: foo
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://babeljs.io/scripts/repl.js?t=2015-05-21T16:46:33+00:00:263:11), <anonymous>:24:9)
    at REPL.evaluate (https://babeljs.io/scripts/repl.js?t=2015-05-21T16:46:33+00:00:263:36)
    at REPL.compile (https://babeljs.io/scripts/repl.js?t=2015-05-21T16:46:33+00:00:210:12)
    at Array.onSourceChange (https://babeljs.io/scripts/repl.js?t=2015-05-21T16:46:33+00:00:288:12)
    at u (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js:28:185)
```

which is exactly what I would like from the extended error.

My goal is to extend `Error` into a variety of subclasses and use them in bluebird's `catch` matching. So far, that is failing miserably.

Why is the subclass not showing a message or stack trace?

**Edit:** [using Chrome's built-in subclassing](https://jsfiddle.net/5e3kakqj/) (thanks to @coder) works perfectly. This isn't specific to Babel, necessarily, as the following example (from [@loganfsmyth on Babel's gitter feed](https://gitter.im/babel/babel?at=555f678f727234850fc7656d)) shows:

```
// Works
new (function(){
  "use strict";
  return class E extends Error { }
}());
// Doesn't
new (function(){
  "use strict";
  function E(message){
    Error.call(this, message);
  };
  E.prototype = Object.create(Error);
  E.prototype.constructor = E;
  return E;
}());
```

Comment: I don't think it's a Babel problem. If you use the old way to extend Error you get the same missing stack (on Chromium41).

Comment: can you confirm the browser you using ? seems to be working for chrome v42 https://jsfiddle.net/5e3kakqj/

Comment: @coder on Chrome 42 as well. Your example works, but the Babel version does not.

Comment: @dystroy You're right. Included a minimal example someone came up with on babel's gitter that shows simple fake inheritance failing and real ES6 inheritance working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, extending using babel's transpiled code only works for classes built in a specific way, and a lot of native stuff doesn't appear to be built like that. Babel's docs warns that extending many native classes doesn't work properly.

You could create a buffer class that creates the properties "manually", something like this:

```
class ErrorClass extends Error {
  constructor (message) {
    super();

    if (Error.hasOwnProperty('captureStackTrace'))
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    else
       Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
          value: (new Error()).stack
      });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'message', {
      value: message
    });
  }

}
```

Then extend that class instead:

```
class FooError extends ErrorClass {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

---

**Why doesn't it work as you'd expect?**

If you look at what is transpiled, you'll see that babel first assigns a copy of the super class' prototype to the sub class, then when you call `new SubClass()` this function is called:

```
_get(Object.getPrototypeOf(FooError.prototype), "constructor", this).call(this, message)
```

Where _get is a helper function injected into the script:

```
(function get(object, property, receiver) {
  var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property);

  if (desc === undefined) {
    var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);

    if (parent === null) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return get(parent, property, receiver);
    }
  } else if ("value" in desc) {
    return desc.value;
  } else {
    var getter = desc.get;

    if (getter === undefined) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return getter.call(receiver);
  }
});
```

it does something like finds the `constructor` property descriptor of the sub class' prototype's prototype and tried to call its getter with the new subclass instance as context if it exists or return its value (`if ("value" in desc)`), in this case the Error constructor itself. It doesn't assign anything to `this` from the super call so while the new object has the right prototype, it didn't get constructed the way you expect. Basically the super call does nothing to the newly constructed object, just creates a new `Error` which isn't assigned to anything.

If we use the `ErrorClass` defined above, it does adhere to the class structure as expected by Babel.

Comment: This seems right. You can only extend certain native objects using the native syntax.

Comment: I (think) this will work properly when ES2015 classes are running natively in browsers (vs transpiled to ES5, as some features are impossible to shim).

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation due to the downlevel compilation of ES6 to ES5. Find more about this in TypeScript's [explanation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work).

As a workaround you can do:

```js
class QueryLimitError extends Error {
  __proto__: QueryLimitError;

  constructor(message) {
    const trueProto = new.target.prototype;
    super(message);
    this.__proto__ = trueProto;
  }
}
```

In some cases cases `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, FooError.prototype);` might be enough.

You'll find more information in the corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965) and the