# Combine Array with Error in a single type

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a promise-based library (for Node.js 0.10 - 6.x) with a method that rejects with an `Array`.

When using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) it results in a warning: `a promise was rejected with a non-error`.

Wrapping the array into a custom error type is easy, but I want to avoid breaking the library's backward compatibility.

Is it possible to implement such an object that could be used as an array, while being seen by [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) as an `Error` object at the same time?

**extras**

When inheriting from `Error` I use the following helper for compatibility with Node.js 0.10 - 0.12:

```
function inherits(child, parent) {
    child.prototype.__proto__ = parent.prototype;
}
```

And looking at the [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) source, maybe there is a way to circumvent its verification somehow:

```
Promise.prototype._rejectCallback =
function(reason, synchronous, ignoreNonErrorWarnings) {
    var trace = util.ensureErrorObject(reason);
    var hasStack = trace === reason;
    if (!hasStack && !ignoreNonErrorWarnings && debug.warnings()) {
        var message = "a promise was rejected with a non-error: " +
            util.classString(reason);
        this._warn(message, true);
    }
    this._attachExtraTrace(trace, synchronous ? hasStack : false);
    this._reject(reason);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript don't permits real multiple prototypal inheritance.

You can "extend" `Error` but the subclass can't be both `instanceof` an `Error` and an `Array`.

If [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/d62e20741eb759a50aa7af13c5dc7fb2bfbf2694/src/promise.js#L487) use [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) you can try to subclass `Array` object and simulate `Error` behavior (interface and and properties), but this depends strongly of Bluebird error-check implementation.

I think is better and robust to wrap the array value into an Error property/attribute.

Comment: `is better and robust to wrap the array value into an Error` - as i stated, the main reason I asked the question is to avoid breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: So you can try to subclass Array with Error interface (like trace property, etc). Looking at Bluebird source it don't use `instanceof Error`. But you can have issues in the future if they change it.

Answer (score -1):

So long as your environment allows subclassing `Error`, yes!

I asked about something similar while [extending errors to create my own subtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402287/extended-errors-do-not-have-message-or-stack-trace), which is essentially what you want to do. In fact, I've done something similar to create HTTP-specific errors that include the response's status code.

Assuming your environment does allow `class SubError extends Error` (and there is a workaround if not), you simply do:

```
class ErrorWithData {
  constructor(msg, data = []) {
    super(msg); // this changes with the workaround
    this._data = [].concat(data); // make a copy for safety's sake
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

If you're in an older browser that does not allow you to subclass `Error`, you can use the shim class from [@Mosho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403029/129032) and replace `extends Error` in that example with `extends ErrorClass`.

NodeJS will allow you to `extends Error` [from v4](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node4) and on, with [v6 having correct/full support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node6) for it. Earlier versions require Mosho's workaround.

Comment: I've just updated my question - it is specifically for Node.js (0.10 - 6.x)

Comment: Some of those allow `extends Error`, some don't. Per https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, v4 and v5 require `use strict` (incorrectly) and v6 allows subclassing Error in general, but v0.10 and v0.12 will not.

Comment: I already use a shim for sub-classing under Node.js 0.10 - 0.12, it works fine. I assume it can be done there also? :) `function inherits(child, parent) {
    child.prototype.__proto__ = parent.prototype;
}
`

Comment: I believe `Error` has some extra properties (like the stack trace) that will be lost if you simply copy the prototype. You should try it and see.