# instanceof custom error class returning false

Tags: javascript

Why does this result in false?

```
'use strict';

class InvalidCredentialsError extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.name = 'InvalidCredentialsError';
  }
}

const err = new InvalidCredentialsError('');

console.log(err instanceof InvalidCredentialsError);
```

But this returns true:

```
console.log(err instanceof Error);
```

[image]

Comment: What is `err`? Do you mean `const errClass = new InvalidCredentialsError(); console.log(errClass instanceof Error);`?

Comment: It also looks like `err` is `undefined` in the code you've provided, and `errClass` is not a class instance, but a reference to the class itself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Apologize! I forgot to copy the complete code! Updated now :)

Comment: Your updated code now produces a true evaluation... not false.

Comment: @evolutionxbox http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKKwJJ?editors=0011

Comment: @evolutionxbox The first instanceof is false, this is what I'm confused about!

Comment: That's odd. When I run this code in Chrome I get `true` and `true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133447/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-karl-morrison).

Comment: It's a transpiler limitation. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30402287/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Alright!

Comment: This is also a known limitation in TypeScript. See [this blog post](https://www.dannyguo.com/blog/how-to-fix-instanceof-not-working-for-custom-errors-in-typescript/) and [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work). As workaround, set the prototype manually at the end of the constructor: `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, InvalidCredentialsError.prototype);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works...you need to construct an **instance** of your type, then `instanceof` will return whether your object is indeed an **instance** of that type.

```
'use strict';

class InvalidCredentialsError extends Error {
  constructor(msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.name = 'InvalidCredentialsError';
  }
}

var err = new InvalidCredentialsError("Hello, world!");

console.log(err instanceof InvalidCredentialsError); // true
```

**Note** `const errClass = InvalidCredentialsError;` will just create an alias for your type, so you could do this...

```
var err = new errClass("Hello, alias");
console.log(err instanceof errClass); // true
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKKwJJ?editors=0011

Comment: @KarlMorrison, that's odd...I ran the same code in FireBug console and Chrome console and I get true x2.

Comment: @series0ne it's either a babel or a codepen bug. OP just added a screenshot of what they see.

Comment: Must be a babel bug as I get the same results in node.